# Can't seem to pass param from VF page into my Controller

Tags: apex, controller, apex-param

I want to pass a parameter from my VF page into a method in controller.

VF

```
<div id="output_table">

     <apex:form >
        <div onclick="Attach.showDeleteConfirmDialog('deleteConfirmDialog{!attach.id}')" class="del_link"></div>

          <div id="deleteConfirmDialog{!attach.id}" style="display: none;"
                            title="Deleting {!attach.name}">
                            <apex:outputText value="Are you sure?" />
               </div>
     </apex:form>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="doActualDeleteAttachment" action="{!deleteAttachment}" rerender="output_table"></apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:param name="attachmentToDeleteParam" value="00Pd000000AcDf1" assignTo="{!selectedAttachmentId}" />            
    </apex:form>

</div>
```

So I've hardcoded the value for test purposes.

Controller

```
public String selectedAttachmentId {get; set;}

public PageReference deleteAttachment() {
    Attachment attachment = getSelectedAttachment();
    delete attachment;
    return null;
}

private Attachment getSelectedAttachment() {
    return [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id=:selectedAttachmentId];
}
```

If I simply hardcode an Id into getSelectedAttachment(), it works fine so as far as I can tell, the problem is with the param not being passed into the controller.

```
       <script>
        var Attach = (function() {

            function showDeleteConfirmDialog(id) {

                jQuery('#' + id).dialog({
                    resizable : false,
                    modal : true,
                    buttons : {
                        'Yes' : function() {
                            jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                            doActualDeleteAttachment(id);
                            return true;
                        },
                        'No' : function() {
                            jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                showDeleteConfirmDialog : showDeleteConfirmDialog
            };

        }());
    </script>
```

Would anyone have any suggestions?

SUCCESS!!

After messing with the code for a while, I realised I was passing

```
deleteConfirmDialog{!attach.id}
```

into the controller, not just

```
{!attach.id}
```

So the following code now works!

```
<div onclick="Attach.showDeleteConfirmDialog('deleteConfirmDialog{!attach.id}', '{!attach.Id}')" class="del_link"></div> <--EXTRA ID CALL
```

and

```
       <script>
        var Attach = (function() {

            function showDeleteConfirmDialog(id, attachId) <--EXTRA ID VARIABLE{

                jQuery('#' + id).dialog({
                    resizable : false,
                    modal : true,
                    buttons : {
                        'Yes' : function() {
                            jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                            doActualDeleteAttachment(Id); <--INCORRECT ID
                            doActualDeleteAttachment(attachId); <--CORRECT ID
                            return true;
                        },
                        'No' : function() {
                            jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                showDeleteConfirmDialog : showDeleteConfirmDialog
            };

        }());
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to post a visualforce code where you call the actionFunction. I think a problem is there.

Comment: I added it there. I hope it helps!

Comment: Try to use only one `apex:form` tag ([best practice using  forms](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_form.htm)) and you have to leave the `value` parameter of the `apex:param` empty while passing values, like this `value=""`

Comment: I've made those changes mast0r but still no luck.

'List has no rows for assignment to SObject'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `apex:param` is **outside** of the `apex:actionFunction`. Other code looks ok, but it is uclear what changes you have made on it. So i will post here a working example of passing parameter. Try to modify your code based on this template:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public String passedParam { get; set; }
    public MyController(){
        // It is important to initialize a string here
        passedParam = '';
    }

    // This method just outputs the passed value
    public void checkParam(){
        System.debug('### passedParam: ' + passedParam);
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="test2">

    <!-- Only one form tag for all components -->
    <apex:form>

        <apex:actionFunction name="sendParam" action="{!checkParam}" reRender="none">
            <apex:param name="p1" assignTo="{!passedParam}" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <a href="#" onclick="sendParam('someString')">Send it</a>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Debug output:

```
USER_DEBUG|[43]|DEBUG|### passedParam: someString
```

Comment: So after solving my first problem, it never would have worked as my param was outside the actionFunction anyway. Cheers for the formatting advice too.

Answer (score 3):

use actionfucntion like below because in your code param is outside from the action function which is not the right way. Please give it a try and let us know.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="doActualDeleteAttachment" action="{!deleteAttachment}" rerender="output_table">
        <apex:param name="attachmentToDeleteParam" value="" assignTo="{!selectedAttachmentId}" />  

</apex:actionFunction>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<apex:param name="attachmentToDeleteParam" value="" assignTo="{!selectedAttachmentId}" />
```

Change your param code to the above to set its value to id which you are sending from your javascript code.

Comment: Please be more clear while answering questions. At the moment your answer have no details and it is very unclear what is your solution.

Comment: I think Jaffer means I should set my param value to 'value="id"', which is the variable I have declared n my JS. I have already tried that and it didn't work.

Thanks anyway Jaffer

Comment: Yeh that code was missed. I have posted my new answer.